# How can I attach a file to a Sendgrid Single Send Email?

Tags: sendgrid

All the stack overflow questions I've seen about sending an email attachment in Sendgrid involve the v3 API. I'm just looking to use one of the Single Send marketing emails, although there is nothing I can find in the Sendgrid UI to attach anything to a single send email. Sendgrid is difficult to get in touch with. Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The SendGrid Web UI, and the Marketing Campaigns platform as a whole, do not support message attachments.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to this is to **upload file in Google Drive or Dropbox and add a link** in the email.

No need to attach anything to the email.